# error with partial declaration of 'BitmapSource.main page'must not specify different base classes

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, bitmapsource

i got an error with partial declaration of 'BitmapSource.main page'must not specify different base classes.

In my XAML, I have

```
x:Class="BitmapSource.MainPage", xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone", xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
```

Then in **MainPage.g.i.cs** there the error that highlight is public partial class **MainPage** Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage

How to solve it?

Comment: Check your XAML vs code behind files, you probably have a namespace/class name difference somewhere. Or your type in the XAML is not the right one (<Page> for instance).

Answer (score 0):

I will go for a long shot and say that the problem is caused by the potential [BitmapSource confusion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). The easy test to see whether this is the case or not - rename your project to something else other than BitmapSource and see if the issue persists.